# SQL MAX Date Does Not Decipher Seconds

Tags: sql-server, max

I have a table which contains the following data:

```
ID    | ObjectID     |  ActionDate
=======================================
12345 | 422107       | 2016-10-05 11:24:23.790
12346 | 422107       | 2016-10-05 11:24:28.797
```

I want to return the ID and max date, but the MAX function does not seem to be calculating down to seconds value (SS).  Am I missing something, or is this a limitation with the MAX function?  Here is the code I am using:

```
SELECT  
    TMOA.ObjectID           AS [ObjID]
    , TMOA.ID               AS [ObjActionID]
    , MAX(TMOA.ActionDate)  AS [PrepDate]
FROM    
    TM_Procedure            AS TMPRD
    left join TM_ObjectAction       AS TMOA     ON TMPRD.ID = TMOA.ObjectID
GROUP BY    
    TMOA.ObjectID
    , TMPRD.ID
    , TMOA.ID
```

Comment: Why group by more than just one column?

Comment: `max()` most definitely takes seconds into account. What is the result you get? Having `TMPRD.ID` in the group by looks wrong though

Comment: Even when I skinny down the SELECT and GROUP BY clauses, I am still not getting the right result.   SELECT 
     DISTINCT TMOA.ID    AS [ObjActionID]
     , MAX(TMOA.ActionDate) AS [PrepDate]
    FROM 
     TAAG.dbo.TM_ObjectAction   AS TMOA
    WHERE 
     TMOA.TypeLID = 3    --Prepared Status
     AND TMOA.ObjectTypeLID = 4  --Procedure Type
    GROUP BY 
     TMOA.ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're grouping by the ID of the table which is `UNIQUE`. More than likely that's why you're getting a record that you don't want. Just select the `MAX(ActionDate)` and see what you get.

If you get the records you want, then you have to figure out which column you are selecting/grouping by that is causing the records you don't want. My guess is that it's either `TMOA.ObjectID` or `TMOA.ID`

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the window function Row_Number()

```
Select * 
 From (
        Select *
              ,RowNr=Row_Number() over (Partition By ObjectID Order by ActionDate Desc
         From  YourTable 
      )  A
 Where RowNr=1
```